# How to toggle or disable function lock on Windows 10 via UI/CMD?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, function-keys

I know it seems like a basic question, but I haven't been able to solve it after 5 hours of Googling and trying different things.

I currently have to hold the function (FN) key to perform various common actions, every space in this question required holding FN. I'm certain it's due to function lock, and I strongly suspect my toddler enabled it while bashing away at the keyboard.

I have verified that it is not a hardware issue by loading windows advanced startup and seeing the keyboard work as expected.

I can safely say it isn't any standard key combination. I've tried combining every likely key combination.

I'm now looking for an advanced method. There has to be a software method to fix this, such as altering or adding registry keys, or something else - anything!

**How can I access/edit the function key settings in windows via the UI or command line?**

Additional details:

Laptop: Toshiba Satellite Pro L770-12F Upgraded to Windows 10 Pro

Toshiba support haven't got a clue and I'm well outside of my warranty. Have looked at many related forum posts and all similar posts already on SU but none provide a software method.

Comment: Try pressing <f11>

Comment: Fn-Esc worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many stories of this problem on the internet, and all seem to talk about needing some Toshiba tools that are no longer available.

[One in particular](https://forum.toshiba.eu/showthread.php?83956-Satellite-L775-11N-Uprgade-Windows-10-FN-key-problem&p=322371&viewfull=1#post322371) though mentions a somewhat unorthodox option:

> **SOLVED** - for me anyway but worth a try.
>
> Go into device manager & uninstall the pointing device - for me it was
>   a **Lenovo pointing device**!.
>
> Restart Windows & ALL the keys now work as they should.
>
> I hope this is the universal solution for everyone!!

Just *why* this causes the problem is difficult to know. It is possible that there is a misdetected keyboard or HID device which is effectively "holding" a key down.

Comment: I don't know how I ever got a Lenovo Pointing Device in the first place, or how it affects this, but this solved it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I access/edit the function key settings in windows via the UI?

> 1. Save all your open documents and stuff and close their respective programs
> 2. Navigate to the following directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Toshiba\System Setting
> 3. Double-click on the "System Settings.exe"
> 4. Scroll down in the left menu until you find "keyboard"
> 5. Click on the "keyboard" menu option and change the default "special function mode" to "normal f1-f12"
> 6. Click the "apply" button and allow your computer to restart.

Source [fn key seems to be reversed](http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-1913222/key-reversed.html)

Check also the Fn sticky settings in Start > All Programs > TOSHIBA > Utilities > Accessibility:

> The TOSHIBA Accessibility utility allows you to use the Fn key to
>   create a hot key combination with one of the function keys without
>   pressing the two keys simultaneously as is usually required. Using
>   Accessibility lets you make the Fn key a sticky key, meaning you can
>   press it once, release it, and then press a function key to activate the
>   hot key function.
>
> [image]

Source [User's Guide for Satellite/Satellite Pro L750D/L740D/L730/L740/L750 Series](http://support.toshiba.com/support/staticContentDetail?contentId=3116945&isFromTOCLink=false)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I've tried both and I don't have the settings available. Have installed all available software from Toshiba.